# com.google.android.gms:play-services is not working

Tags: android, google-play-services

`com.google.android.gms:play-services` are giving errors, they were working fine, but when I pres the run button in the for testing purpose the these all libraries just vanish. I don't know what to do ??

```
    dependencies {
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.4.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //noinspection GradleCotestApimpatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.1.2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.1.2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.Commit451.YouTubeExtractor:youtubeextractor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.rtoshiro.fullscreenvideoview:fullscreenvideoview:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'in.gauriinfotech:commons:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.shamanland:xdroid-toaster:0.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.daasuu:animateHorizontalProgressBar:0.2.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had the same issue then I tried every answer, clean the code, rebuild project with graddle, invalidate the cache and restart, checking the dependency > classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' , these were the most populated suggestions. but none of them worked, then I check my network connection that was poor, due to a long time for downloading dependency either it timed out or gave the same error. please check your connection first and then apply these solutions.